# Why would this class be abstract?

Tags: java, optimization

In my AP Computer Science class, we've been going through the [GridWorld](https://apstudent.collegeboard.org/apcourse/ap-computer-science-a/gridworld-case-study) case study. While looking at it, it seems that the class AbstractGrid has no reason to be abstract, as it has no abstract methods or values. Why would this be?

**More information**

If it was just to force implementation of the Grid interface, why doesn't it have those methods as abstract methods (thus forcing the signatures of those classes anyway without the interface). Also, both of the children override most of it's methods anyway.

```
package info.gridworld.grid;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class AbstractGrid<E> implements Grid<E>
{
    public ArrayList<E> getNeighbors(Location loc)
    {
        ArrayList<E> neighbors = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (Location neighborLoc : getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(loc))
            neighbors.add(get(neighborLoc));
        return neighbors;
    }

    public ArrayList<Location> getValidAdjacentLocations(Location loc)
    {
        ArrayList<Location> locs = new ArrayList<Location>();

        int d = Location.NORTH;
        for (int i = 0; i < Location.FULL_CIRCLE / Location.HALF_RIGHT; i++)
        {
            Location neighborLoc = loc.getAdjacentLocation(d);
            if (isValid(neighborLoc))
                locs.add(neighborLoc);
            d = d + Location.HALF_RIGHT;
        }
        return locs;
    }

    public ArrayList<Location> getEmptyAdjacentLocations(Location loc)
    {
        ArrayList<Location> locs = new ArrayList<Location>();
        for (Location neighborLoc : getValidAdjacentLocations(loc))
        {
            if (get(neighborLoc) == null)
                locs.add(neighborLoc);
        }
        return locs;
    }

    public ArrayList<Location> getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(Location loc)
    {
        ArrayList<Location> locs = new ArrayList<Location>();
        for (Location neighborLoc : getValidAdjacentLocations(loc))
        {
            if (get(neighborLoc) != null)
                locs.add(neighborLoc);
        }
        return locs;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a string that describes this grid.
     * @return a string with descriptions of all objects in this grid (not
     * necessarily in any particular order), in the format {loc=obj, loc=obj,
     * ...}
     */
     public String toString()
     {
         String s = "{";
         for (Location loc : getOccupiedLocations())
         {
             if (s.length() > 1)
                 s += ", ";
             s += loc + "=" + get(loc);
         }
         return s + "}";
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some relevant code in form of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so people here could help yiu

Comment: Why not ask your teacher?

Comment: Thank you Todd for adding in the code.

Answer (score 8):

Since `AbstractGrid<E>` implements `Grid<E>`, but doesn't implement all of its methods, it has to be declared `abstract`.

Any non-`abstract` subclass of `AbstractGrid<E>` will need to implement those methods.

Answer (score 0):

The class is abstract because multiple types of "Grid" classes inherit from it. While AbstractGrid contains common methods/variables, it cannot function by itself. Therefore, it is abstract.

Had to take this exam last year, good luck =)